# Lazy loading: How do I do Model.include(:name) when foreign key has a different name than the model?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want lazy load a user into my Target objects in Active Record like this:

Target.include(:user)

But the problem is that the user_id foreign key is named 'targeted_user_id', not 'user_id'. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Target < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user, foreign_key: 'targeted_user_id'
end

Target.includes(:user)
```

good explanation [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)